# Describing the contents of your wish

Tags: phrase-request

What’s the best way of presenting the “contents” of my wish if they consist of one desired happening and two more happenings that should precede it?

The desired happening: the “wishee” (the person on whom the “wisher” is bestowing his wish) must find what he wants in his life;

The first happening that should take place prior to that: the “wishee” must reach the full age (the age of 18);

The second happening that should take place before the desired one: the “wishee” must become independent;

1) Should I use a gerund with a relative clause?:

> I wish him only one thing – **finding** what he wants in his life after
>   **he has reached the full age and become independent**.

2) Or should I use gerunds everywhere?:

> I wish him only one thing – **finding** what he wants in his life after
>   **reaching** the full age and **becoming** independent.

3) Or should I use a to-infinitive clause with a relative clause?:

> I wish him only one thing – **to find** what he wants in his life after
>   **he has reached the full age and become independent**.

4) Or should I use a to-infinitive clause with gerunds?:

> I wish him only one thing – **to find** what he wants in his life 
>   after **reaching** the full age and **becoming** independent.

5) Or should I use a so-that construction with a relative clause?:

> I wish him only one thing – **so that** (he would find / he finds) what he
>   wants in his life after **he has reached the full age and become
>   independent**.

6) Or should I use a so-that construction with gerunds?:

> I wish him only one thing – **so that** (he would find / he finds) what he
>   wants in his life after **reaching** the full age and **becoming**
>   independent.

7) Or should I use a so-that construction with embedded “having + past participle” construction?:

> I wish him only one thing – **so that**, **having reached the full age
>   and become independent**, (he would find / he finds) what he wants in
>   his life.

8) Or what?

Comment: "the full age" is not idiomatic. Do you mean to say "the age of majority" or "adulthood"?

Comment: "Do you mean to say "the age of majority" or "adulthood"?" - Yes, I meant adulthood. Is "the age of majority" same thing?

Comment: "the age of majority" is a legalistic phrase and is defined by applicable law.  "adulthood"  can be either legalistic and precise, or refer in general terms to maturity bur not to a specific age. It's hard to tell from your examples which is appropriate.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I noticed you've dropped that m dash from my sentence and replaced it with a comma. Would dash look kind of weird to an average American reader's eye in my sentence?

Comment: The rules of punctuation are a more-or-less agreed upon set of typographic conventions, and there is considerable variation. It would be somewhat unusual to use an em-dash to introduce a *that*-clause, but it's not impossible. Given the register of your sentence, a comma would be better IMO. You could use a colon there, an em-dash, or a comma. A colon would probably seem a little antiquated to some readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are idiomatic:

> I wish him only one thing, that he find ... when he reaches ... and has become independent
>
> I wish him only one thing, that he finds ... when he reaches ... and has become independent

A speaker of AmE, I would choose the former, **that he find** (subjunctive).  A speaker of BrE might choose the simple present, **that he finds**.

Comment: One more small question: you said, "when he reaches". Does "after he reaches" sound a bit weird to a native English speaker?

Comment: @brilliant: Many native speakers might say **after he reaches** in such a context but to my ear  **when** is simpler and better as it does not have the implication of *sequence*. You are wishing him well **in** his adult years.

Comment: If you have time, please, check out another question of mine about this same sentence: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/179002/turning-a-subjunctive-dependent-content-clause-into-a-past-tense